# How can I create a unique id in this pandas dataframe with datetime and number entry?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
miles     dollars  gallons  date      gal_cost     mpg       tank%_used    day
0   253.2   21.37   11.138  2019-01-15  1.918657    22.732986   0.821993    Tuesday
1   211.9   22.24   11.239  2019-01-26  1.978824    18.853991   0.829446    Saturday
2   258.1   22.70   11.708  2019-02-02  1.938845    22.044756   0.864059    Saturday
3   223.0   22.24   11.713  2019-02-15  1.898745    19.038675   0.864428    Friday
```

I'd like to create a new column called 'id' that is unique for each entry. For the first entry in the df, the id would be c0115201901 because it is from the df_c dataframe, the date is 01 15 2019 and it is the first entry.

I know I'll end up doing something like this

`df_c = df_c.assign(id=('c'+df_c['date']) + ?????)`

but I'd like to parse the `df_c['date']` column to pull values for the day, month and year individually. The df_c['date'] column is a datetime64[ns] type.

The other issue is I'd like to have a counter at the end of the id to count which number entry for the date it is. For example, 01 for the first entry, 02 for the second, etc.

I also have a df_m dataframe, but I can repeat the process with a different letter for that dataframe.

Comment: @anky_91 just fixed the question, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [pandas datetime-properties docs.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#datetime-properties)

The date can be extracted easily like

```
df_c['date'].dt.day + df_c['date'].dt.month df_c['date'].dt.year
```

Comment: That's super helpful, thanks! Any ideas how to create the last part of the id?

Comment: Use the index `df_c.index`

Comment: That would work, but is there a way to order the items by the date? Where the first entry is c0115201901 and if I had another entry that day it would be c0115201902?

Comment: `df_c['idx'] = 1` and then `df_c['idx'].cumsum()`

Comment: I ended up using df_c['date'].dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y") and that worked well